# How to get Windows Identity details in certificate authentication

Tags: wcf, x509certificate

How to get Windows identity details while using Certificate Authentication in WCF? I am getting NULL when I use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity. Also, when I use ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name -- this return claims value due to certificate authentication.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Using certificate authentication,The server cannot get the windows identity of the client,only the relevant information about the certificate can be obtained.

If you want to obtain the client's windows identity on the server-side,you can consider adding a method that the client passes the windows identity to the server.

```
            [OperationContract]
            void GetWindowsIdentity(string WindowsIdentity);
```

This is the OperationContract of the server-side.

```
           public void GetWindowsIdentity(string WindowsIdentity) {
        Console.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity:" + WindowsIdentity);
    }
```

This is the realization of the method.

```
    client.GetWindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

Client-side passes windows identity to server-side.